# Throttle function execution in dart

Tags: dart, flutter, throttling, rxdart

Is there a way in `Dart` to throttle function execution like this

`Observable.throttle(myFunction,2000);`

Comment: `thottle` or `debounce` from https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart should provide that. https://medium.com/fantageek/throttle-vs-debounce-in-rxswift-86f8b303d5d4 might be related.

Comment: I am not sure how to incorporate this information with what I have, is listening on buttons is valid with flutter?

Comment: In Dart a function that is going to be called repeatedly is most commonly a listener on a `Stream` - do you have a `Stream` here and you're trying to throttle the function passed to `listen`? If that is the case we should think of this as throttling the stream instead of the function. For that use `values.transform(throttle(Duration(seconds: 2))).listen(myFunction)`.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform

If this isn't a Stream listener can you elaborate on the use case? Do you need a `Function` you can pass as an argument?

Comment: I want to throttle function execution, for example imagine there is a button that is going to send a request to an api, I want the button to be always clickable but throttle the api call for 1 call every 1 minute for example, so user can click as much as they want but I will only send one request per minute.

Comment: You can use a StreamController to transform function calls to a Stream. Perhapsrxdart Observable provides something out-of-the-box to do that.

Comment: "for example imagine there is a button that is going to send a request to an api"

Does that button expose presses in a Stream? It does on the web...

Answer (score 3):

Using https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/throttle.html

So, your example in Dart 2 with RxDart is

```dart
final subject = new ReplaySubject<int>();
myCaller(Event event) {
  subject.add(event);
}
subject
  .throttle(Duration(seconds: 2))
  .listen(myHandler);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// you can run the code in dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/
typedef VoidCallback = dynamic Function();

class Throttler {
  Throttler({this.throttleGapInMillis});

  final int throttleGapInMillis;

  int lastActionTime;

  void run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (lastActionTime == null) {
      action();
      lastActionTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    } else {
      if (DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - lastActionTime > (throttleGapInMillis ?? 500)) {
        action();
        lastActionTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      }
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  var throttler = Throttler();
  // var throttler = Throttler(throttleGapInMillis: 1000);
  throttler.run(() {
    print("will print");
  });
  throttler.run(() {
    print("will not print");
  });
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    throttler.run(() {
      print("will print with delay");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `static int lastActionTime;` so, if you use several instances of `Throttler` class they all will share the same `lastActionTime`?

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. I edit the answer by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code for throttling regular functions:

```dart
class Throttler {
  final int milliseconds;

  int _lastActionTime;

  int get _millisecondsSinceEpoch => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

  Throttler({required this.milliseconds})
      : _lastActionTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

  void run(void Function() action) {
    if (_millisecondsSinceEpoch - _lastActionTime > milliseconds) {
      action();
      _lastActionTime = _millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
final throttler = Throttler(milliseconds: 100);

throttler.run(() => print('1'));
throttler.run(() => print('2'));

// only '1' is printed
```

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Günter Zöchbauer you can use a `StreamController` to transform the function calls to a `Stream`. For the sake of the example let's say that `myFunction` has an `int` return value and an `int` parameter.

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

// This is just a setup for the example
Stream<int> timedMyFunction(Duration interval) {
  late StreamController<int> controller;
  Timer? timer;
  int counter = 0;

  void tick(_) {
    counter++;
    controller.add(myFunction(counter)); // Calling myFunction here
  }

  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(interval, tick);
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    if (timer != null) {
      timer?.cancel();
      timer = null;
    }
  }

  controller = StreamController<int>(
    onListen: startTimer,
    onPause: stopTimer,
    onResume: startTimer,
    onCancel: stopTimer,
  );

  return controller.stream;
}

// Setting up a stream firing twice a second of the values of myFunction
var rapidStream = timedMyFunction(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

// Throttling the stream to once in every two seconds
var throttledStream = rapidStream.throttleTime(Duration(seconds: 2)).listen(myHandler);
```

---

Note: pay attention to the extra parameters of the [throttleTime](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ThrottleExtensions/throttleTime.html). The defaults are `trailing=false` and `leading=true`. If you want to keep the latest sample within the throttle period then you rather want `trailing: true` and `leading: false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:async';

// A simple class for throttling functions execution
class Throttler {
  @visibleForTesting
  final int milliseconds;

  @visibleForTesting
  Timer? timer;

  @visibleForTesting
  static const kDefaultDelay = 2000;

  Throttler({this.milliseconds = kDefaultDelay});

  void run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (timer?.isActive ?? false) return;

    timer?.cancel();
    action();
    timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), () {});
  }

  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
  }
}

// How to use
void main() {
  var throttler = Throttler();

  throttler.run(() {
    print("will print");
  });
  throttler.run(() {
    print("will not print");
  });
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
    throttler.run(() {
      print("will print with delay");
    });
  });

  throttler.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is great. Feels like the opposite of a Debounce class I have already

Comment: Added a count integer that increases the timer duration after every action.